# MIPS addi $t2, $zero, ' '

Tags: assembly, mips

I understand that $t2 is a temp variable holder. 
The $zero register is a register that always holds the value of 0.

So, does the line `addi  $t2, $zero, ' '`:

- Add the ASCII value for a space to 0 and stores it in $t2?
- Or is an empty space treated as a value of 0?

Comment: `' '` is a character, so it'll take the ASCII code instead of 0. `'\0'` will be equal to 0

Comment: So what is the value of a space? :)

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Are you asking what [the ASCII encoding of `' '` is](http://www.asciitable.com/)?   You could have answered your own question by looking at disassembly output.  You should do that if you're still confused.

Comment: I'm asking whether the addi function adds the ASCII value of the character space to t2, or whether I'm missing the point entirely

Comment: The result is `' '` (or 32, or 0x20, or whatever you want to view that sequence of bits as).